# How to remap "Context Menu" key in Mac OS X?

Tags: keyboard, key, shortcut, remap

I have a Logitech keyboard (Ultra-Flat Keyboard Dark Shine to be exact), which has the context menu key in the middle of the windows and alt key, which is quite annoying.

Here's a screenshot of where the key is:

http://freshlog.com/grabs/ff532-How_do_I_remap_the_context_menu_key_in_Mac_OS_X

I can remap the windows and alt keys under the default Keyboard System Preferences Panel, but there doesn't seem to be a way to remap the context menu key.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 49):

Use [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) ([Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) for osx 10.9, 10.10). As Mecki pointed out, XML .keylayouts / Ukelele can't solve your problem.

In spite of the name, KeyRemap4MacBook works on any Mac (OS X 10.4 or later).

The settings you want are under "For PC Users" » "Change PC Application Key".

[image]

Comment: Using @David's suggestion, map it to `Option_L`

Comment: Why would you want to map it to command-L? To quickly go to the location bar in your browser?

Comment: @avernet when Karabiner says "Command_L" it means the Left Command key.

Comment: Does Karabiner need to be left running for this to work?

Comment: @SamanthaCatania - Sort of. You can close the Karabiner GUI completely when you're not actively configuring Karabiner. Karabiner itself is a kernel extension, so it's always running in the background.

Answer (score 8):

Use `KeyRemap4Macbook`. Edit `private.xml` file like this:

```xml
<item>
    <name>Change Windows context menu key to Right option key</name>
    <identifier>private.win_context_menu_option_key</identifier>
    <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::PC_APPLICATION, KeyCode::OPTION_R</autogen>
</item>
```

This code will remap right option key to the context menu key.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Karabiner to map <kbd>App</kbd> to <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>:

[image]

You can then use Keyboard Maestro to map <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Letter</kbd>, where <kbd>Letter</kbd> is a key that denotes an application, to focus the application:

[image]

For example, you can then do <kbd>App</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to focus Chrome, <kbd>App</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to focus Terminal, <kbd>App</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to focus Slack etc. (if an app isn't already open, Keyboard Maestro opens it first).

If you're using a generic keyboard, then you have a dedicated App key:

[image]

If you're using an Apple keyboard, you have to hold <kbd>Command</kbd> and <kbd>Option</kbd>, but they are next to each other, and appear on both sides of the spacebar:

[image]

Keep in mind that OS X already uses <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to open the **Force Quit Applications** dialogue, so you could now use <kbd>App</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> for that. Likewise, OS X uses <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to close all of the windows in the focus application (tabs in Chrome).

Notes:

- [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) is an open source kernel extension for modifying the way keyboard input is handled by OS X.
- [Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) is a proprietary application for creating keyboard shortcuts in OS X. It has a free 30 day trial, and costs $36.

Comment: Keyboard Maestro changed my life! Automate EVERYTHING!

Answer (score 4):

The latest MacOS versions are served by Karabiner Elements 12.1.
Key-to-key remapping are done in the `Simple Modifications` tab and conveniently selected in 2 rows of drop-down-menus (see: screenshot).

`Complex Modifications` in this Preferences Panel's tab have either to be added by importing them from the internet (Karabiner-E.'s site) or from the user's `~/.config/karabiner/assets/ complex_modifications` folder.
"Complex" ones from the net actually are also copied there and switched "on" (= `[+ Enable]`) in the tab.

ALL modifications are finally stored (& thus "activated") in `~/.config/karabiner/karabiner.json`.

A pragmatic procedure (that also helps avoid mistakes while writing complex-mods yourself) is to copy & rename & alter one "imported" mod.
Once you are experienced (e.g.: different bracket types) it may be easier to edit the json file directly…

[image: (Inline graphic shows part of drop-down-menu)]

There is no longer the option to constrict remaps to specific windows (can be simulated by an osascript AppleScript) as some other features.
A non-Element version of Karabiner is being developed.

Two sites to get information & questions (answered) – but please search for previous "doubles" !:

[github.com >> Karabiner-Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements/issues/)
[groups.google.com/forums/ osx-karabiner](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/osx-karabiner)

Comment: Since this answer helped me but is closed here, here's the link to my shorter, updated version of it answering [Switch the keys caps lock and shift](https://superuser.com/a/1804009/) on SuperUser.

Answer (score 2):

[KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/)

Entry: For PC Users -> Change PC Application Key -> Application Key to Option_L

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the latest macOS Sierra doesn't support [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner) yet. An easy solution is to convert `capslock` key with `command` key.

Comment: I currently use Keyboard Maestro to work around the limitations of Karabiner Elements. I use KM to map my App key to F18, and then use [this macro](https://forum.keyboardmaestro.com/t/how-to-make-any-key-a-new-modifier-key/6809) in KM to make F18 a new modifier key.

Comment: Karabiner Elements works in Sierra. The application (or context menu) key can be found as "application" and can be mapped to e.g. "right_option" which in my case made my Microsoft Ergo keyboard match the layout of my MacBook laptop.